# Hibernate Criteria order by with two column

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a table with wingNo and FlatNo.

```
WingNo          FlatNo
A                001
A                002
B                1
A                101
```

etc

I need to order by WingNo & FlatNo in Asc order. Where WingNo & FlatNo both are String.
The result should be:-

```
WingNo         FlatNo
A               001
A               002
A               101
B               1


criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("wingNo"));
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("flatNo"));
```

How can I use the order by with String filed treated as numbers?

Answer (score 0):

If the `FlatNo` field be a fixed-width text or varchar field in your database table, then your current ordering logic should already be giving you the behavior you want.  This is because zero-padded fixed width number strings sort lexicographically identically to the underlying numbers.

If the `FlatNo` column does not have fixed width and/or could be missing left zero padding, then you would have to do more work.  If you had this long term need, it might just be easier to make `FlatNo` a numeric column.